# fglrx freeze upon lockscreen or lid close when iGPU selected

Tags: ati, radeon, fglrx

My system has hybrid (and I believe muxless,i.e. only the integrated card is actually connected to the display) graphics. The first card is an `Intel HD 4400`, and the second card is the `AMD Radeon HD 8670M` (solar system series, not OLAND). Thus, currently the open-source `radeon` driver does not support the card, and I am forced to use the proprietary `fglrx` driver.

**Why not just turn the dGPU  card off without fglrx?**

I have no need of fancy graphics and would be happy to simply turn the discrete ATI card off, so long as it was *properly* switched off and was not overheating/eating battery. The options to do this without `fglrx` and `pxpress` seemed limited to me: I have no `vgaswitcheroo` switch (even before `fglrx` was ever installed) and I can only deduce this was because the `radeon` driver does not yet support my card/does not properly load it yet, see my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408222/no-vga-vgaswitcheroo-in-sys-kernel-debug-ubuntu-13-10) for more on that and the things I tried. Other methods like `acpi_call` have been reported as at best "proof of concept" and at worst dangerous, so I'd rather not venture into using them. More reliable projects like `bumbleebee` are nividia only.

**Simply leave the AMD card driverless**

Relying on just the `i915` intel driver works flawlessly, no bugs, no problems, however the AMD card is then left UNCLAIMED and could possibly lead to overheating/battery drain, so I am not so happy about that.

**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with fglrx**

I started here, and experienced a bug when the `iGPU` was selected. This bug manifests itself whenever the screen is locked, the laptop lid is closed, or even when the computer is left inactive with something like `xscreensaver` installed instead with no lockscreen enabled. It causes a black screen with a moveable cursor only; switching tty and back does not recover, and a restart from the tty is needed. It does not happen every single time but happens pretty regularly, at least once or twice day. All saved work is lost.

I tried both the `fglrx` in the repos, and the latest 13.10 from the AMD website. No change.

When the dGPU is selected instead (from the AMD Catalyst control centre, or ultimately by pxpress) this bug does not occur, but I had another bug which I won't bother getting into here.

**Ubuntu 13.10 with fglrx**

A very similar bug here but not quite as severe. Exactly the same conditions, namely lockscreen, lidclose, inactivity (if xscreensaver is being used). This time the frozen screen is not black, but a picture of your desktop at the moment of the freeze, again with moveable cursor. Here I only tried the latest fglrx AMD drivers 13.10.

Again no problems with just the `i915` driver (no `fglrx`) and again no problems with `dGPU` selected.

**Some things I tried:**

1) Disabling `vsync`. I tried this both in compiz settings manager, and by `aticonfig --sync-vsync=off` followed by reboot. *No change*.

2) Turning DPMS off. `Option      "DPMS" "false"` in the `xorg.conf` monitor stanza. (Of course, I also changing gnome settings "Do Nothing/Don't suspend" for battery and AC too).*No change*.

3) `Option "AIGLX" "off"` in server flags of `xorg.conf`. *No change*.

4)  Modifying the `atieventsd` so it worked properly for Ubuntu, see my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409815/fglrx-and-the-broken-atieventsd-daemon-maybe-improve-your-battery-life-for-amd). And also, running without it. *No change*.

5) Booting with the options

```
Option      "Capabilities" "0x00000800"
Option      "KernelModuleParm" "locked-userpages=0"
Option      "NoAccel" "True"
```

in the `xorg.conf` Device stanza. *No change*.

6) Booting with `nomodeset` as kernel parameter. *No change*.

7) Turning off `acpi` interaction from `aticonfig`:

```
--acpi-services=off
--acpi-display-switch=off
```

*No change*.

**Why does it work with just intel?**

One thing I don't understand is why it works with the just the intel `i915` driver. I thought `pxpress` would just hand over control to that driver on bootup, so if it worked with the `i915` alone, I'd have expected it to work with pxpress selecting `igpu`.

I know `fglrx` installs its own libGl implemenation also, but it switches back to the old stock MESA libGL implementation when the intel card is selected (c.f. `/usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibGL` python script).

So when `igpu` selected, it should be exactly equivalent to life before `fglrx` after a reboot?

Comment: First off, what hardware is it? Ive been fighting to get 12.04 to install drivers for a newer edition radeon, and ive seen all of the outputs youve posted, and ive seen them all change with different drivers ruinning. dont know how drivers affect detection that much but apparantly they do. I think you should decide based on what hardware is ACTUALLY in there and what you need it to do( hardware acceleration, 3d stuff, etc

Comment: Well it's a Radeon HD 8670M (Mars XT, solar system series). the open source radeon driver does not support my card yet anyway (not to be confused with OLAND), so I pretty much had no choice but to use fglrx drivers. I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and use the latest AMD Catalyst 13.12, and they work OK, bar the fact that when I choose the iGPU I get a freeze on lockscreen/lid close which switching to a tty and back cures (on 12.04 this freeze needed a restart from the tty)

Comment: Still experiencing issues? What about a live cd?

Comment: I would try to remove completely the fglrx (since it doesn't happens with a live cd) and then install it again following the same principle as the live cd (you may want to check the driver used by the live cd) or try to upgrade to 13.10. If that doesn't work you should consider reinstallation.

Comment: I rewrote this question to reflect the current state of my efforts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time looking into this, I came to release the key point: when fglrx/pxpress loads the Intel driver, it does so with the `UXA` acceleration method, whereas by default (on a Haswell system running 13.10, pre-fglrx install) the Intel driver would load with the `SNA` acceleration method.

I tested by booting with an `xorg.conf` that looked like:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Intel Graphics"
        Driver          "intel"
        Option          "AccelMethod"  "UXA" # (fglrx uses this) I can see the bug
        #Option          "AccelMethod"  "SNA" #(default) no bug!
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
           Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Now even this Intel `xorg.conf` gave the freeze bug after a lid close or two. Yet booting with the exact same config file, only with

```
Option          "AccelMethod"  "SNA"
```

I got no bug whatsoever, no matter how many lid closes/screen locks (this is the default method for the driver anyway, and this is why I was perplexed, because it fooled me into thinking all was good with the intel driver and fglrx was tainting things).

Now that I realised this was a intel driver problem, some googling led me to discover a fix. Create a file `~/.drirc` to config the DRI settings, containing

```
<device screen="0" driver="dri2">
        <application name="Default">
                <option name="vblank_mode" value="0"/>
        </application>
</device>
```

This turns off `vsync` (the setting that makes your GFX card sync to the screen refresh rate, rather than speeding away at its intrinsic framerate, to avoid tearing). Note: there is no point turning off `vsync` with aticonfig as in my OP as this will just turn it off for the dGPU not the Intel card. I'm not sure why my attempt at turning it off with Compiz Settings Manager did not work though.

Even with the `UXA` method, turning off `vsync` this way stopped the crash, even for the `fglrx` `xorg.conf`.

Even better would be to somehow configure `pxpress` to load the Intel driver with the `SNA` options, see my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411632/hybrid-graphics-change-igpu-driver-options-when-using-fglrx)