# Hybrid graphics: change iGPU driver options when using fglrx?

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, intel, fglrx

Normally when wanting to change the intel driver options `xorg.conf` can just be edited like:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

for example to choose the acceleration method.

How is this achieved when using `fglrx` drivers on a hybrid graphics system (with intel and AMD cards) and an `xorg.conf`, by default (`aticonfig --initial` generated) looks like

```
Section "ServerLayout"
       Identifier     "My Layout"
       Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

(I tried adding an intel device stanza with desired options; it leads to a segfault)